# Two select box changes when one chage not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have three select box in my webpage, Once i select the first box it, the second and third box value should be change according to the data-id,
Once i change the First box my second and third box value are changing but the problem is, The options of the second and Third box is same.. I have given my code below

```js
var $select1 = $("#select1");
var $select2 = $("#select2");
var $select3 = $("#select3");
$select1.data('options', $select2.html())
$select1.change(function() {
  var val = $select1.val();
  var options = $($select1.data('options')).filter('[data-id="' + val + '"]');
  $select2.html(options);
  $select3.html(options.clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="send_request.php" name="myForm1" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate1());">
  <select class="regtext sec1test" name="select" id="select1" style="width:99%">
    <option value="0">Select What?</option>
    <option value="1">Features</option>
    <option value="2">Video</option>
    <option value="3">Buy1</option>
    <option value="4">Buy2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="sec1 lef">
    <select name="type" class="regtext sec1test" id="select2" style="width:99%">
      <option id="0" value="0">Select genre</option>
      <option value="1" data-id="1">abc1</option>
      <option value="0" data-id="1">abc2</option>
      <option value="5" data-id="1">abc3</option>
      <option value="2" data-id="2">models</option>
      <option value="3" data-id="3">Comp</option>
      <option value="4" data-id="4">Beat</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="sec1 lef">
    <select name="name" class="regtext sec1test" id="select3" style="width:99%">
      <option id="0" value="0">Select genre</option>
      <option value="1" data-id="1">abc</option>
      <option value="2" data-id="2">mod</option>
      <option value="3" data-id="3">Comp</option>
      <option value="4" data-data-id="4">Beat</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here my problem is Once i select features The Second Box shold display the abc1,abc2,abc3 and the third box should display abc alone, but the result is both the box has abc1,abc2,abc3., So please guide me how to rectify it

Comment: The second and third selct box have a same name attribute,

Comment: I have changed the name attribute but still its not working

Comment: I posted a solution . Hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your updating the third box by the options value of the second box which you are filtered already and clone them to the third box, so you need to make separate data for each control to avoid overlapping between controls options

try to change you js codes as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $select1=$("#select1");
    var $select2=$("#select2");
    var $select3=$("#select3");

    $select1.data('options1', $select2.html())
    $select1.data('options2', $select3.html())

    $select1.change(function(){
        var val=$select1.val();
        var options1 = $($select1.data('options1')).filter('[data-id="'+val+'"]');
        var options2 = $($select1.data('options2')).filter('[data-id="'+val+'"]');
        $select2.html(options1);
        $select3.html(options2);
    });
});
```

i tested these changes and works fine

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to filter the list of choices of selec2 and select3 according to data-id=val :

```
$select1.change(function() {
  var val = $select1.val();

  $select2.find('[data-id!="' + val + '"]').hide();
  $select2.find('[data-id="' + val + '"]').show();

  $select3.find('[data-id!="' + val + '"]').hide();
  $select3.find('[data-id="' + val + '"]').show();

});
```